# Accessing vuetify v-text-field value for another text field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to make a username suggestion based on users first and last name.
The idea is after user finished **first name** and **last name** field, the **username** field value will be first + last name.

```
firstName = Bobby
lastName = Brown
username = BobbyBrown
```

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="firstName"
    label="First Name"
></v-text-field>

<v-text-field
    v-model="lastName"
    label="Last Name"
></v-text-field>

<v-text-field
    v-model="username"
    label="Username"
></v-text-field>

<script>
export default ({
  data() {
    return {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        username: '',
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean "suggestion" as in the placeholder text or the default value?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean as the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`username` should be declared as computed property with set/get methods:

```
<script>
export default ({
  data() {
    return {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
       
    }
  },
computed:{
   username:{
      get(){ 
           return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
        },
      set(val){
          const [first,last]=val.split(' ');
          this.firstName=first;
          this.lastName=last;
        }

}
})
</script>
```

Comment: This trigger "Variable declaration expected" in VScode from vetur extension.

Comment: I've made a mistake here `const =[first,last]=val.split(' ');` you should remove the first `=`

Comment: Only need it one way from firstName lastName to username, so I remove `set(val)` block, works for me.